# My Time Field in my DBGrid is showing the date and time instead of time only - delphi

Tags: delphi, dbgrid, tdbgrid, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a field in my database called 'Times', it's a date/time format and its format is set to 'short time'. In my database the date does not show, nor is it being add to the database as I know. It is only the time value. My DBGrid shows the time field with the time value and the date '12/30/1899'. How do I get rid of the date in my time field.

Here is the code I used to submit to the database.
Get time value:

```
bookingtimes:= timeof(dttime.Time);
```

Submit to Database:

```
 tblbooking.FieldByName('Times').AsDateTime:=bookingtimes;
```

Example of DBGrid 'Times' column output:

```
12/30/1899 7:02:01AM
```

Comment: If you ask about setting display format, setup `DisplayFormat` e.g. to `hh:mm:ss` for your persistent field. Or declare a persistent calculated field and strip the date portion at calculation. Or remove the date portion inside a SQL command (by using `CAST`). I'm a bit confused about the used [tag:datetimepicker] tag here though.

Comment: @Victoria Agreed `DateTimePicker` hasn't effect on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you mean this will work for you, just follow this steps:

- This is your issue:

[image]

- Double click on your table, and select `Times` field:

[image]

- After you click on your field, go to the `Object Inspector` and find `DisplayFormat` property:

[image]

- Write the `format`, in your case `hh:mm:ss`:

[image]

- Now let's see the result:

[image]

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed step by step, however I do not have displayformat when I click on my Times field. What do I do to obtain that? My column returns as a TColumn rather than a TDateTimeField

Comment: @crackedlogic Did you right click on the table then hit `add all fields`?

Comment: Yes, then I clicked on the 'Times' field and moved to the object inspector.

Comment: @crackedlogic Can you edit your question and add a screenshot shows field editor next to the object inspector please.

Comment: I just realized my mistake, I have been looking at the dbgrid rather than the adotable

Comment: When i click on 'Add all fields' or 'Add fields' i get the message:
'Empty SQL Statements'